# Can Power Automate or any other method pre-populate a Microsoft Form with values from a spreadsheet

Tags: sharepoint, power-automate, microsoft-forms

I'm working with Sharepoint/Forms/Power Automate to try to make a very manual process I inherited more efficient.  Currently a number of users across the country put some input data into spreadsheets and email them to me.  I copy/paste their inputs into a workbook that has a lot of linked formulas...the end result is a table with % changes from the last reporting period, color coded by magnitude and statistical significance.  I then have to cut and paste that back into a PowerPoint deck.

What I have now is a Microsoft Form on a Sharepoint site where they can enter their inputs, and Power Automate stores them in the appropriate place in the calculation workbook.  (I'm still working on Power BI to get the table out).

BUT...the users have to fill out every field on the input form (there are 15 of them), even if only one number has changed.  Because if they leave it blank, Power Automate just sticks a blank in the calculation workbook. I'd like the Form to open with the current values (read in from the calculation workbook) so that anything that is unchanged just gets written back.

From what I can tell with Power Automate, the only trigger in Forms is when a response is submitted.  If there were a trigger for opening a Form maybe I could have Power Automate pre-populate the form.  And I can't find anything in the settings for the Form that would allow pre-populating.

Is there another avenue to accomplish this?

Comment: There are no REST API’s for Forms, therefore, there’s nothing you can do. They’re static.

Comment: Boo.  But at least now I know.  Thanks!